# Fast, accurate algorithm for sum of cubed primes

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-mathematics

I am looking for an algorithm to quickly calculate the sum of the cubes of primes. More formally, this function:
$$ f(n) = \sum_{p \in P} p^3, P =  \{ p \in [2, n]: p \text{ is prime} \}$$

In my case, $n$ is somewhere around $10^{12}$, so the naive approach of sieving for primes, then adding their cubes is too slow and memory prohibitive. What would be some more efficient approaches that could still give me the exact solution?

Comment: Assume that such an algorithm exists. What can you say then about $f(n)-f(n-1)$ ?

Comment: If you apply summation by parts and the prime number theorem you easily get a bound for $f(n)$. For which purpose do you need the exact value of $f(n)$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, it might be a coincidence, but this would be quite useful for https://projecteuler.net/problem=606 , and the bound is essentially the same.

Comment: Having solved Project Euler problem 606 using both brute-force summation of prime cubes to around 10^12 (you need to first solve problem 548 to understand their relevance) via libprimesieve and also via a superior sublinear algorithm which turned out to be 8 times faster over the range in question for that problem, I can confirm there are better approaches than brute force sieving and summation.  I do not want to provide a proper answer and spoil the problem though.  There is a bit of a pointer in https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?p=49040 (where it mentions "sublinear").